# Calculating percentage from MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Am trying to find the **top 5 selling books**.

My idea of calculating the **top 5 selling books** is this:

```
percentage = number_of_SUCCESS_transactions_each_book / total_number_transactions_each_book

Fetch the result(book_id, percentage) sorted in DESC order, with a LIMIT of 5
```

Here's a simple representation of the table containing data for the sake of understanding:

```
tblPayments
-----------
trans_id | book_id | payment_status | purchase_date
---------------------------------------------------
1   |   233 | SUCCESS   | 2017-04-05
2   |   145 | FAILED    | 2017-04-10
3   |   233 | FAILED    | 2017-04-05
4   |   233 | SUCCESS   | 2017-04-05


tblBooks
--------
book_id | book_name
-------------------
233 | My Autobiography
145 | How to learn English
201 | Finding Nemo
```

I will be querying for this **top 5 selling books** between a particular date. For example, between `2017-04-01` to `2017-04-25`

What am expecting as output is something like this:

```
book_id | book_name  | percentage
----------------------------------
233 | My Autobiography      | 67
145 | How to learn English  | 0
201 | Finding Nemo          | 0
```

After brainstorming for hours, this is what am thinking of:

```
SELECT b.`book_id`, ( 
    (   
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tblPayments` WHERE `book_id` = b.`book_id` AND `payment_status` = 'SUCCESS' ) / 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tblPayments` WHERE `book_id` = b.`book_id` ) 
    ) * 100.0 ) AS `percentage` 
FROM `tblPayments` AS b 
WHERE b.`purchase_date` BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-25' 
GROUP BY b.`book_id` 
ORDER BY `percentage` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Can it be further improved? Will it be causing any performance issues in database?

Right now am in train back to my home. So am writing this from tablet, out of from my head. I would be able to test it out when I reach back home in around 6 hrs time. So I thought to ask it here in the mean time.

Or do you have suggestion on a better approach than this?

Thank you

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to both @Strawberry and @Stefano Zanini for the answers.

Just one more doubt. Will it be okay if I just `JOIN` that with `tblBooks` to get the `book_name` field in the resultset?

I mean, this `tblPayments` table is supposed to have a ton of rows. So will `JOIN` be okay? Or I should get this 5 rows in PHP and do another query just to get the `book_name` of each of these 5 books? What would be efficient method?

Comment: A left join (and coalesce) will be fine.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you. Can you tell me where you are suggesting the `coalesce` to be used? Is it to prevent division by 0 error?

Comment: In the SELECT (or perhaps the SELECT of an outer query); to return 0 when NULL would otherwise be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transactions;

CREATE TABLE transactions
(transaction_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,book_id INT NOT NULL
,transaction_status VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL 
,transaction_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO transactions VALUES
(1,233,'SUCCESS','2017-04-05'),
(2,145,'FAILED','2017-04-10'),
(3,233,'FAILED','2017-04-05'),
(4,233,'SUCCESS','2017-04-05');

SELECT book_id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_status = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) success_rate 
  FROM transactions 
 GROUP 
    BY book_id
+---------+--------------+
| book_id | success_rate |
+---------+--------------+
|     145 |       0.0000 |
|     233 |       0.6667 |
+---------+--------------+
```

I've left out the trivial bits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Appreciate it! I have one more small doubt regarding the inclusion of the `book_name` in the resultset. I have edited my question with the details. Please check and let me know your suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can improve that query by replacing the inner queries you use for the percentage with conditional sums:

```
SELECT b.`book_id`,
       SUM(case when `book_id` = b.`book_id` AND `payment_status` = 'SUCCESS' then 1 end) /
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 AS `percentage` 
FROM   `tblPayments` AS b 
WHERE  b.`purchase_date` BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-25' 
GROUP BY b.`book_id` 
ORDER BY `percentage` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**Edit**

Addressing your new question: there's no need to do a second query intermediated by PHP, you can do everything in a single query:

```
select  t1.book_id, t2.book_name, t1.percentage
from    (
            SELECT b.`book_id`,
                   SUM(case when `book_id` = b.`book_id` AND `payment_status` = 'SUCCESS' then 1 end) /
                   COUNT(*) * 100.0 AS `percentage` 
            FROM   `tblPayments` AS b 
            WHERE  b.`purchase_date` BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-25' 
            GROUP BY b.`book_id` 
            ORDER BY `percentage` DESC
            LIMIT 5
        ) t1
join    tblBooks t2
on      t1.book_id = t2.book_id
```

That may be faster than joining `tblBooks` in the first query

```
SELECT b.`book_id`,
       c.`book_name`,
       SUM(case when `book_id` = b.`book_id` AND `payment_status` = 'SUCCESS' then 1 end) /
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 AS `percentage` 
FROM   `tblPayments` AS b
JOIN   `tblBooks` AS c
ON     b.`book_id` = c.`book_id`
WHERE  b.`purchase_date` BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-25' 
GROUP BY b.`book_id` 
ORDER BY `percentage` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

But if I were you I'd do a few tests myself to see if the performances are actually an issue, and in that case which query is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I appreciate it! I have one more small doubt regarding the inclusion of the `book_name` in the resultset. I have edited my question with the details. Please check and let me know your suggestion. Thank you